# Set div to background image

Tags: html, css

I want to set a `<div></div>` with an image inside using CSS that targets the div's id instead of using `background-image: url("bg.jpg");` . My image `<div></div>` looks like this:

```
<div id="background">
  <img src="imgs/bg1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Thanks in advance you your help

Comment: isn't `background-image: url("bg.jpg");` applied using CSS? :|

Comment: Sorry I must have misunderstood the`background-image: url("bg.jpg");` tag, I wanted CSS that targeted the div contents using `id="background"` instead of the image source

Comment: This is not a "tag", but a CSS rule. Tags are the keywords you write after a "<" and "</", not including the element's attributes.

For selecting an element with id=background you use the CSS selector "#background"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out, here is the code
HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="style/imgs/bg1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}

#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 90%;
  min-height: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but your question is paradox.

Using `background-image: url(bg.jpg)` is CSS and the way to go. You can use that CSS rule inside a style attribute on the div like this:

```
<div id="background" style="background-image: url(bg.jpg);"></div>
```

or you could put the rule in a style block in the head of your HTML page like this:

```
<head>
....
<style type="text/css">
#background {
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
....
```

or you can put it in a CSS file you include in your page.

In either case I suggest you consult a good book about HTML and CSS. This way you'll also learn when to use which method.